# Adding const keyword breaks Path.Combine call

Tags: c#, .net

No idea why when I change this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

    public static class Constants
    {
        public static string  MainCarFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "\\Cars.csv");
    }
```

to this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;


    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string MainCarFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "\\Cars.csv");
    }
```

That now it breaks and it doesn't recognize the `Combine` method of the Path object `(System.IO)`.

I get `can't resolve Combine`...

Answer (score 9):

`const` requires that the value be constant at compile time.

Use `public static readonly string`, instead.

Comment: You need to use `static readonly` in order to duplicate the constant behavior for the runtime. static readonly will be evaluated once while instance readonly requires a class instance and will be evaluated each time a new instance is created

Comment: Thanks, Polity. Fixed. I should have seen that, especially considering that it's a static class.